# What does 'SSL value is 0' mean

Tags: postgresql, ssl, amazon-rds

I am reading this [AWS RDS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Enabling.html) for Postgres that states:

**requires that the SSL value be 1**

What doe this mean? I was not able to find any flag in RDS setting that is set to 1 or 0. Is this some internal Postgres property? How can I change it for the RDS if yes?

Comment: What's your db version?

Comment: My DB Engine version is 11.1

Comment: looks like it's not supported, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html

Comment: PostgreSQL versions 10.6 or higher, 9.6.11 or higher, and 9.5.15 or higher.

Comment: Seems to me that 11.1  is higher than 10.6.

Comment: I think the doc is referring to the major version, so `10.6 or higher` means 10.6-10.13.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose an editable (non-default) "parameter group", then you can use the parameter group editor to search for this parameter, and then change it from 1 to 0.  This will disable connecting over ssl.

However, there is probably no reason to do this. If you are running your own PostgreSQL, setting up ssl is a bit of a pain so there is no reason to do it if you don't plan on using it.  But since RDS automatically sets it up for you, that is not a concern.